# Basic Definition of Diff Operator

Tags: differential-operators

I'm looking at up at how to properly define a differential operator, that is, explicitly write it as a mapping between function spaces.

Well, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator) defines it by setting a mapping $A$ between function spaces $\mathcal{F}_1 ,\mathcal{F}_2$ and. It goes on to say that a given a $u\in\mathcal F_1$, a $k$-order PDO finitely generated by $u$ is defined as:
\begin{equation}
P(x,\partial_x)=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}a_{\alpha}(x)\ \partial^{\alpha}_x
\end{equation}

For what I figure to be some $a\in\mathcal F_1$. Whereas the equation itself feels natural, I'm having trouble understanding the purpouse of the preliminaries on the definition. That is, what's the need to define a preliminar map that serves the purpose of some function of it's domain generating the operator. I suppose what I'm asking is: Why do we need to construct something to generate the operator instead of simply defining:
\begin{equation}
P:\mathcal{F}_1\rightarrow\mathcal{F}_2
\end{equation}

I'd guess that it has to do with the multi-index, but I can't formalize it. Maybe, my question will reduce to just what it properly means that a function "generates" a diff operator.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not every mapping between two function spaces is a differential operator.

Comment: yeah, of course, I meant a general mapping $P:\mathcal{F}_1\rightarrow\mathcal{F}_2$ with $P(x,\partial)$ defined in a rather similar way.

Comment: In that case you are misunderstanding the wikipedia article. The introductory sentence is meant to be in a conversational tone instead of a formal one as it is meant to be illustrative to those unfamiliar with the topic. That is, there is no mathematical need to defining $u$ and $f=A(u)$ specifically in advance. The "finitely generated by $u$" is meant to be an after comment explaining in words what the definition of the operator does.

Comment: In order to help "visualizing" things, the writer adds a example, which has nothing different, within the formal definition, and uses it to say that it gives the operator itself, in a general manner. How can that be more intuitive than saying that the diff op takes the functions (represented via multi-index), and yields a map that gives the linear comb? Hence, yes, the functions are generating the image, but that follows from the principle that the diff op acts on the differentiation op, which is why the thing is constructed in the 1st place.

Comment: I get the intention of the writer, but I think is more misleading than helpful. Seens strange for an wikipedia article on maths, which is usually nicely written.